# Is there any way to Create "Gradient" Background color for "wizard Control" in ".net 4.5"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, .net-4.5, wizard

How can I Create "Gradient" Background color for "wizard Control" in C# (asp.net) ".net 4.5"?

```
<asp:Wizard ..>
```

like the following image:

[image]

Comment: Are you using WebForms? If so, Add it as a tag. (ASP.net includes more than just WebForms now)

Comment: Did you try creating the gradient using CSS and then apply to wizard control using CSSclass property? It should work this way too.

Comment: @Nimesh i did. but it just apply the gradient color to background of wizard. not navigation or header part.

Comment: @jpaugh what do U mean?

Comment: Can you update the question with CSS and the screenshot of current output?

Comment: @s.m Are you using ASP.NET *WebForms*? Or, *WinForms*, perhaps? ASP.NET is a big thing, with many components. Knowing which one you are working with would really help you get an expert answer from someone who knows about that component specifically.

Comment: @s.m. Adding a new tag for WebForms or WinForms would makes it easier for someone familiar with that technology to find your question.